# How do I fix a Pylance problem with "import sys"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am a total beginner to programming and I am trying to use import sys to create a shopping list in Python. However, import sys is returning a "Expected module name Pylance" problem and the letters in sys aren't changing color to signify that it is working. Also, the red squiggly line will appear starting right after import sys, but it doesn't underline import sys and when I delete "import sys" the red squiggly line is still there on that line and I have to close VS Code and reopen it to get the error to go away. Am I missing an extension or is it something else?The first image shows what it looks like with import sys and the second shows what it looks like after I delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Install Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)  or change the Python language server back to the default